# Why my logic is failing in certain test cases?

Tags: c++, pointers, error-handling, max, greedy

I am solving this problem on codeforces :
https://codeforces.com/contest/1492/problem/C

My code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define int long long

int32_t main() {
    
      int n,m;
      cin>>n>>m;
      string str1,str2;
      cin>>str1;
      cin>>str2;
      
      int i=0;
      int p=0;
      vector<pair<int,int>>vec;
      while(i<n && p<m)
      {
          int j=i;
          int q=p;
          while(j<n-1 && str1[j+1]==str1[i])
          j++;
          while(q<m-1 && str2[q+1]==str2[p])
          q++;
          
          vec.push_back({i,i});
          vec.push_back({i+q-p,j});
          
          i=j+1;
          p=q+1;
      }
      int maxi=1;
      for(int i=0;i<vec.size()-1;i++)
      {
          maxi=max(maxi,vec[i+1].second-vec[i].first);
      }
    cout<<maxi<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My logic:
For each character in t , I am finding the maximum and minimum valid indexes in s which are possible to be taken.
Consider this example:

```
s-->"aaaabbbbbc"
t-->"aabc"

so my vector would be [(0,0) , (1,3) , (4,8) ,(9,9)]
```

However my code is failing in certain cases. Can someone point out the mistake?

Comment: What in your question is specific to C++14 or 17 ? If there is none - please remove those tags.

Comment: If your aim is to learn C++ then do not use competitive coding sites, they teach you problem solving skills (true) but also horrible coding skills/styles (e.g. `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, `using namespace std`, using `#define int long long` etc....) Learn from C++ books or https://www.learncpp.com/. first and have a look at https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines. Your problem could wel be with operator precedences add extra `(` and `)` in your while loops to make more clear what you mean.

Comment: `#define int long long` OMG. Illegal code of course, you cannot redefine keywords like that. `int32_t main` is illegal too.

Comment: @john this is a regular practice in competitive coding.

Comment: @VatsalAMehta That doesn't change the fact that it is not legal C++. Nor does it bring any benefit (that I can see). Certainly that style of coding isn't going to help in a job interview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't seem to be implementing your algorithm. In the loop you have

```
      vec.push_back({i,i});
      vec.push_back({i+q-p,j});
```

So the resulting vector would be alternating pairs of equal indexes and (potentially) different indexes. But:

```
[(0,0) , (1,3) , (4,8) ,(9,9)]
```

The `(4, 8)` pair can't be produced by `{i, i}`. Further the first pair in your example doesn't fit your stated algorithm either, the first `a` can be `(0, 2)`.

Your code also seems to assume the letters in the strings are sorted. But what about this input?

```
s = "aaabbbaaabbbccc";
t = "abc";
```

You would only match `a` with the first triplet of `a`s and `b` with the first triplet of `b`s and break down on the `c` completely.